# Excel: compare two cells containing strings and return TRUE if multiple words match

Tags: excel, string, compare, match, formula

I am trying to compare two cells containing strings.  I can't use VBA for restrictive reasons on my computer so it's just formulas for me.   This is what I have:

One cell is there to enter lots of text to explain a problem statement.  Another cell is nearby containing a handful of keywords - may or may not be separated by commas (depending on what works!). So an example...

The product keyword cell might have: Camera, torch, messenger, internet

In the problem description cell I might write: "I am after a phone that can take good pictures with a 50mp camera and I can use the internet to look at the news"

The solution I'm after...In another cell I want to return the value of TRUE, if even one or more than one word matches - I don't need to know how many matches there were, just if there was a match somewhere and return TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking essentially for an `OR` condition. From there just a couple lookup functions. `Find` will search case sensative, while `Search` will not.

Depending on your version of excel, you could use this for a dynamic solution with `B2` being your sentance and `B3` being your list of words separated by a comma (make sure spaces arent an issue).

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(B3,","),B2)))
```

[image]

Or a more hard-coded solution for older versions... of excel that just puts the words in the formula

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Camera",B2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("torch",B2)),
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("messenger",B2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("internet",B2)))
```